# Can't load the BIG csv file to apply logit from statsmodel.api

Tags: python, csv, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I am trying to apply the logit function of statsmodel.api with python in order to construct a logistic regression model.

Because my train data has 7GB, it is impossible to load the hole data and apply the

```
logit = sm.Logit(data['binary'], data[train_cols])
```

I am looking for a way to apply my logit function using all my train data

Comment: Even if you could fit the data from the csv file in your memory, then the estimation will most likely still not work because of the requirement for intermediate arrays in the estimation. I don't know if anyone who works with larger datasets has already a solution, but out of core estimation will not be available in statsmodels for at least another few months.

Answer (score 0):

If your machine has more than 8GB of ram, I'd look at pandas.read_csv -- it is amazing.  If not, I'd suggest breaking your data into multiple shards based on type or interval, and then use pandas.read_csv.

link to doc:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html

Also, regardless of whether it fits in memory, you are going to be much much happier breaking it into smaller pieces to test your code -- say 70MB or even smaller.  People always underestimate the pain caused by a long wait between the time you edit code, and see results.

Comment: Thanks for your response :) I have just 8gb of ram, and yes, I am actually using read_csv from pandas and it can't read the csv file.. I splitted the train file to sub-csv-files with less size. It's not the solution because finaly, I can't load all the data in RAM

Comment: Is it all one field, or is it multiple fields, as if its multiple fields, you should be able to get all the data in a given field, and do the regression on that one field, flush the data, and go to the next